# How to deal with AttributeError in dataclass subclass initialization?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass `Walk` with the attribute `vertex_list` and a method `add`. I want to make a subclass `Path` that inherits from `Walk` and has a different implementation for the `add` method.

These are my two classes:

`Walk.py`

```py
from .Vertex import Vertex
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Walk:
    vertex_list: list[Vertex] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, vertex: Vertex = None) -> None:
        cls.vertex_list.append(vertex)

    def add(self, vertex: Vertex) -> None:
        self.vertex_list.append(vertex)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return '--'.join(self.__vertex_list)
```

`Path.py`

```py
from .Vertex import Vertex
from .Walk import Walk
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Path(Walk):

    def add(self, vertex: Vertex) -> None:
        if vertex not in self.__vertex_list:
            self.__vertex_list.append(vertex)
        else:
            pass
```

Trying to initialize a path with a `vertex` named `src` with the line `path = Path(src)` results in the following error:

```
    cls.vertex_list.append(vertex)
AttributeError: type object 'Path' has no attribute 'vertex_list'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am quite the python noob, so links to references will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have an `__init_subclass__` method at all? Neither its existence nor its body make any sense.

Comment: @user2357112 AFAIK, `__init_subclass__` is called whenever `Walk` is subclassed. Alright, now that you point it out, I can understand why it's wrong. What should I be doing instead if want a common constructor?

Comment: ...wait, were you trying to write a constructor there? That should be `__init__`, not `__init_subclass__`. If you want `Path` to inherit `Walk.__init__`, you can use `@dataclass(init=False)` to tell the dataclass decorator to not generate an `__init__`.

Comment: @user2357112 I have already tried that - it results in the same error. And, anyway, isn't `__init__` in a dataclass is used by the `dataclass` decorator to do its job?

Comment: It is, but the constructor you seem to want isn't much like the one the `dataclass` decorator would generate for you - for example, you're trying to take a single vertex object as an argument, rather than taking an optional `vertex_list`.

Comment: The error you got when you tried writing `__init__` was probably because you forgot to set `self.vertex_list` - if you're writing your own `__init__` instead of having `dataclass` generate one, you have to perform that initialization manually.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that's the mistake I did. Now it makes sense. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. I've got it working.

Comment: Also, @dataclass won't allow you to create a non-frozen class inheriting from a frozen one.  (at least not in newer Python's) - if your code did not err in that, it is likely that the semantics does not make sense at all, and your objctes are in some inconsistent state. Just do away with the "frozen" stuff: it does not make much sense, since your `vertx_list` _do_ change.